# Julia - nested loops are consuming a lot of memory

Tags: memory, memory-management, julia

I have a nested loop iteration scheme that's taking up a lot of memory. I do understand that I should not have globals but even after I included everything in a function, the memory situation didn't improve. It just accumulates after each iteration as if there is no garbage collection.

Here is a workable example that's similar to my code.

I have two files. First, `functions.jl`:

```
##functions.jl
module functions

function getMatrix(A)
    L = rand(A,A);
    return L;
end

function loopOne(A, B)
    res = 0;
    for i = 1:B
        res = inv(getMatrix(A));
    end
    return(res);
end

end
```

Second file `main.jl`:

```
##main.jl
include("functions.jl")
function main(C)
    res = 0;
    A = 50;
    B = 30;
    for i =1:C
        mat = functions.loopOne(A,B);
        res = mat .+ 1;
    end
    return res;
end
main(100)
```

When I execute `julia main.jl`, the memory increases as I extend `C` in `main(C)` (sometimes to more than millions of allocations and 10GiBs when I increase `C` to 1000000).

I know that the example looks useless but it resembles the structure that I have. Can someone please help? Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Michael K. Borregaard gave an answer which is very helpful:

```
module Functions                            #1

function loopOne!(res, mymatrix, B)         #2
    for i = 1:B
        res .= inv(rand!(mymatrix))         #3
end
    return res                              #4
end

end

function some_descriptive_name(C)           #5
    A, B = 50, 30                           #6
    res, mymat = zeros(A,A), zeros(A,A) 
    for i =1:C
        res .= Functions.loopOne!(res, mymat, B) .+ 1
    end
    return res
```

However, when I time it, allocations and memory still increase as I dial up `C`.

```
@time some_descriptive_name(30)
  0.057177 seconds (11.77 k allocations: 58.278 MiB, 9.58% gc time)

@time some_descriptive_name(60)
  0.113808 seconds (23.53 k allocations: 116.518 MiB, 9.63% gc time)
```

I believe that the problem comes from the `inv` function. If I change the code to:

```
function some_descriptive_name(C)           #5
    A, B = 50, 30                           #6
    res, mymat = zeros(A,A), zeros(A,A) 
    for i =1:C
       res .= res .+ 1
    end
    return res
end
```

The memory and allocations will then stay constant:

```
@time some_descriptive_name(3)
  0.000007 seconds (8 allocations: 39.438 KiB)

@time some_descriptive_name(60)
  0.000037 seconds (8 allocations: 39.438 KiB)
```

Is there a way to "clear" the memory after using `inv`? Since I'm not creating anything new or storing anything new, the memory usage should stay constant.

Comment: Your code took after a little modification (references to external files) in my julia notebook 435ms and 252MiB (Julia 0.6), there something other wrong with your installation

Comment: By the way, you don't need semicolons in julia

Comment: @stefanbachert does it change when you increase the number of loops? Also, when I tried to use the same functions without doing inv, my code is significantly faster. Is there something particularly wrong with inv?

Comment: @stefanbachert BTW how did you reference to external files?

Comment: Funny to see Julia written like C++

Comment: This was also crossposted to https://discourse.julialang.org/t/nested-loops-are-consuming-a-lot-of-memory/6010; some discussion can also be found there.

Comment: @tryingtosolve: I put all three functions in a julia notebook without external references. That mean to remove "functions." before loopOne in function main

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few pointers at least:

1. The getMatrix function allocates a new AxA matrix every time. That will certainly consume memory. It is better to avoid the allocations if you can, e.g. by using `rand!` to fill an existing array with random values.
2. The `res = 0` line defines `res` as an `Int` but you subsequently assign a `Matrix{Float}` to it (the result of `inv(getMatrix)`). Changing the type of a variable in the code makes it hard for the compiler to figure out what the type is, which makes for slow code.
3. It seems you have a module called `functions` but you don't write it.
4. The `res = inv` code line constantly overwrites the value, so the loop does nothing!
5. The structure and code looks like C++. Try looking at the style guide.

Here's how the code would look in a more ideomatic way that avoids allocations:

```
module Functions                            #1

function loopOne!(res, mymatrix, B)         #2
    for i = 1:B
        res .= inv(rand!(mymatrix))         #3
    end
    return res                              #4
end

end

function some_descriptive_name(C)           #5
    A, B = 50, 30                           #6
    res, mymat = zeros(A,A), zeros(A,A) 
    for i =1:C
        res .= Functions.loopOne!(res, mymat, B) .+ 1
    end
    return res
end
```

Comments:

1. Use a module if you like - it's up to you whether to put things in different files. Module name in caps.
2. If you can, it's an advantage to use functions that overwrite values of an existing container. Such functions end with `!` to signal that they will modify the arguments (like passing a variably by reference without making it const in C++).
3. Use the `.=` operator to indicate that you're not creating a new container, you're overwriting the elements of the existing one. The `rand!` function overwrites `mymatrix`.
4. The return keyword is not strictly needed, but DNF suggested it is better style in a comment
5. The `main` convention isn't used in Julia, as most code gets called by the user, not by execution of a program.
6. Compact assignment format for multiple variables.

Note that in this case, none of these optimisation matter much, as 99% of the calculation time is spent in the expensive `inv` function.

RESPONSE TO THE UPDATE:
There's nothing wrong with the inv function, it just is a costly operation to do. But again I think you may be misunderstanding what the memory counting does. It is not that the memory use is increasing, like you would be looking for in C++ if you had a pointer to an object that was never released (a memory leak). The memory use is constant, but the total sum of allocations increase, because the `inv` function has to make some internal allocations.

Consider this example

```
for i in 1:n
    b = [1, 2, 3, 4]  # Here a length-4 Array{Int64} is initialized in memory, cost is 32 bytes
end                   # Here, that memory is released.
```

For each run through the for loop, 32 bytes is allocated, and 32 bytes is released. When the loop ends, regardless of n, 0 bytes will be allocated from this operation. But Julia's memory tracking only adds the allocations - so after running the code you will see allocation of 32*n bytes.
The reason julia does this is that allocating space in the RAM is one of the costliest operations in computing - so reducing allocations is a good way to speed up code. But you cannot avoid it.

There is thus nothing wrong with your code (in the new format) - the memory allocation and time taken you see is just a result of doing a big (expensive) operation.

Comment: 1. Even if I changed `rand(A,A)` to `[1 2; 3 4]`, I still see the same thing, i.e. memory consumption increases even without using `rand(A,A)`. 4. I'm aware that it does nothing. It's just a workable example. Since I'm not creating anything new, shouldn't memory consumption stay constant?

Comment: No, the total memory use should increase because every time you run the loop you allocate a new Array. As you close the loop that memory is released again, so the code is not leaky - the total memory use at any given time does not increase (depending on when the garbage collector runs). But the memory-tracking capabilities of julia sum all memory that has been allocated over the runtime - because avoiding or reducing allocations is one of the key ways to speed up code.

Comment: How can I make Julia release the memory before the loop is closed? In my actual code, I was assigning new values to the variables and the previously assigned values would never be reused.

Comment: No you don't need to do that, that is done automatically.

Comment: Then the memory usage should stay constant then? The issue is that I'm assigning new values to the variables with the same names, as the previously assigned values are abandoned forever. However, the memory usage still goes up. Therefore, I want the memory to be released _before_ the loop is done.

Comment: I believe you're misunderstanding what the memory usage tracked. It's a cumulative sum of every time there has been a new allocation. Precisely because you arrays are released at the end of scope they have to be allocated anew.
Instead, allocate the array once outside the loop, and just replace the values in the array, e.g. by using the `rand!` command.

Comment: Oh, I just saw you found my answer unhelpful. You're on your own, then.

Comment: So I should a dummy variable outside of the loop and allow the operations within the loop to "fill in" the dummy?

Comment: Sorry! I posted that before I read your comments. I'll give you an upvote when I'm done.

Comment: IMO this is a perfectly clear answer, even without the comments. Upvoted.

Comment: @tryingtosolve I edited the answer to show you what I mean

Comment: What do you mean by "4. No return statement at the end of functions". It's not necessary, but it's definitely good style.

Comment: you think so? I'll change that bit of advice then.

Comment: That's my personal opinion. I like conciseness, but always have a mental hiccup when I see a lone variable hanging on the last line. "What's that for?" before realizing it's a `return` statement. The style guide also shows explicit `return`s.

Comment: Yeah I checked and Base uses that too. I prefer the shorter form, but there you are.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I think I'm confusing memory use with memory **allocation**. I'm running this on a HPC cluster and each iteration increases the memory allocation and my code hits the memory limit very frequently. Is there way to _deallocate_ in Julia?

Comment: That should be automatically taken care of by the garbage collector. I've no experience with HPC clusters, though - maybe try to ask that in a separate question.